# Unkown encryption type?

Tags: encryption, reverse-engineering

200 character long string

GYZDMOJXGQ3GGNZZGJSTMMZWMY3GIMTGGMZDKNRUGQ3TONZYGMYTGMRSGA3WGMRQGYZDMOJXGQ3GGNZZGJSTMMZWMY3GIMTGGMZDINRWMQ3TMNDBG4ZDMYZSGA3WGMRQG4YDMMJXGM3TINRVGYZDMOJWMUZGKNRTGZTDMZBSMY2DQMZTGRRDOMBWGE3TCMZQGZSDAYIK

How ever there are similarities across the string so it cant be a hash i have been cooking this baby with cyberchef however i cant make heads or tails of this. It cant be an alphabetical because of its numbers and it does not look anything familiar. Its not even rot 13. There are no recognizable features unlike rot and base 64. If anyone can identify this i would appreciate it. Ill keep trying.

GYZDMOJXG
Q3GGNZZGJSTMMZWMY3GIMTGGMZDKNRUG
Q3TONZYGMYTGMR
SGA3WGMRQ

GYZDMOJXG
Q3GGNZZGJSTMMZWMY3GIMTGGMZDINRWM
Q3TMNDBG4ZDMYZ
SGA3WGMRQ

G4YDMMJXGM3TINRVGYZDMOJWMUZGKNRTGZTDMZBSMY2DQMZTGRRDOMBWGE3TCMZQGZSDAYIK

Comment: Looks like base32 to me

Comment: It's ascii encoded with hex, then encoded again with base32.